# BASIC language wrapper on C#

Tags: c#, wrapper, basic

Is there any BASIC wrapper / interface for C#? Lua interface wraps lua for C# which works perfect with ability to write user functions, Is there any wrapper that wraps BASIC in C#? I know that BASIC is old, But I just liked the way it's being used and I'm looking for some ways to wrap it as an additional language for my software.

Comment: With "wrap" you mean to made it available for scripting purposes? Take a look to VBA or CS-Script (C# itself made...a scripting language).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft VisualBasic.NET is the companion language to C#.  They are both built on top of the [Common Intermediate Language (CIL) / Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language).

Comment: I'm looking to run BASIC codes in C# and get console outputs from it, Not VisualBasic.